How to adjust this code so that each marker is different based on values in column "Sample"
So, I have this code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming 'thefile' is your DataFrame containing the data

# List of samples to iterate over
samples = ['CZ03', 'K5533', 'K5534', 'L14C', 'L14G', 'L44', 'PT01C', 'PT03C']

# List of columns to be used for coloring and sizing the points
color_columns = ["Li_ppm_m7", "Be_ppm_m9", "Sn_ppm_m118", "Cs_ppm_m133", "Ta_ppm_m181", "W_ppm_m182"]

# Labels for the colorbars
color_labels = {
    "Li_ppm_m7": 'Li (ppm)',
    "Be_ppm_m9": 'Be (ppm)',
    "Cs_ppm_m133": 'Cs (ppm)',
    "Sn_ppm_m118": 'Sn (ppm)',
    "Ta_ppm_m181": 'Ta (ppm)',
    "W_ppm_m182": 'W (ppm)'
}

# Set up the subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(18, 12))

# Flatten the axes array for easy iteration
axes = axes.flatten()

# Iterate over each sample
for sample in samples:
    # Filter data for the current sample
    filtered_data = thefile[(thefile['Mineral'] == 'Bt') & (thefile['Sample'] == sample)]
    
    # Iterate over the color columns and create a scatter plot for each
    for i, col in enumerate(color_columns):
        # Normalize the marker sizes
        sizes = (filtered_data[col] - filtered_data[col].min()) / (filtered_data[col].max() - filtered_data[col].min()) * 100 + 10
        
        # Create a scatter plot with color and size based on the respective column
        scatter = axes[i].scatter(
            x=filtered_data["Sr_ppm_m88"], 
            y=filtered_data["Rb/Sr"], 
            c=filtered_data[col], 
            s=sizes,
            cmap='viridis', 
            alpha=0.7,
            label=sample)  # Use sample as label to differentiate
        
        # Add colorbar
        cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, ax=axes[i])
        cbar.set_label(color_labels[col], fontweight='bold', fontsize=11)
        
        # Set labels
        axes[i].set_xlabel('Sr (ppm)', fontsize=11, fontweight='bold')
        axes[i].set_ylabel('Rb/Sr', fontsize=11, fontweight='bold')
        axes[i].set_xlim(0, 5)
        
        # Rotate the colorbar label
        cbar.ax.yaxis.label.set_rotation(270)
    
# Adjust layout
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()

But I want the marker to vary depending on values in the column: Sample.
Is that possible?
I try defining marker lists, but then the graph comes blank. I read that plt cannot plot marker or style base on the column (like seaborn does). But then, is there any other ways I can do this?

Use a marker list and something like for sample, marker in zip(samples, markers):?
